# in $.extend class how to call internal functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why it doesn't work,it say its not a function,why can't I call myalert() from myalert2?? How to do??

```
var sheepclass = function(handler) {
    this.handler = $.extend({
        'sizes': 'thin',
        'eat': 'grass',
        'color': 'white',
        myalert: function() {
            alert('Hello World');
        },
        myalert2: function() {
            handler.myalert();
            this.handler.myalert(); //this not work either
        }
    }, handler);
}
var blacksheep = new sheepclass({
    'color': 'black'
});
blacksheep.handler.myalert2();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the scope ...

http://jsfiddle.net/78QXc/

```
var sheepclass = function(handler) {
    this.handler = $.extend({
        'sizes': 'thin',
        'eat': 'grass',
        'color': 'white',
        myalert: function() {
            alert('Hello World');
        },
        myalert2: function() {
            this.myalert();
        }
    }, handler);
}
var blacksheep = new sheepclass({
    'color': 'black'
});
blacksheep.handler.myalert2();​
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `this.myalert()` will do

Comment: wow yes, why? it should be handler.something, I made everything inside become handler.size , hander.xxx() then I have to change them all to this... Strange...

Comment: You are extending the handler object and `this` is actually referring to the handler object itself. So you don't have to write `this.handler`.